# table with tableSorter in knockout with computed value for iteration

Tags: knockout.js, tablesorter

We have a table which one show the users with the help of jquery plugin table. When We are using this control with knockout and we iterate the table with a observable Array everything is fine with the help of a handler developed for us:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortTable = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var iden=$(element).attr("id");
            setTimeout( function() {
                if($(element).hasClass('tablesorter')){
                    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
                    $(element).trigger('updateAll');
                }else{
                    $(element).tablesorter({
                        widgetOptions:{filter_external : '#'+iden+"_search"}
                        //headers: {0: {sorter: false}}
                    }).tablesorterPager({container: $('#'+iden+"_pager")});
                }
            }, 0);
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
           $(element).trigger("update");
        }
    };
```

and in the template we do binding in this way:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: MyListObservable">
```

The problem happen when our MyListObservable is a computed value, which one is recalculated in function of other check observable. In this case the behaviour of the control is strange and always add elements to the table but when the observable array remove information this one dont update the index of the table and theirs values. I have tried without success:

1º RemoveAll the values of the array before reload the array.
2º Force the updateAll the table just after of reload of computed value $(element).trigger('updateAll').
3º Get the value of the computed and assign his value to other observable array and iterate with this new array.

Obviously the problem has relation with knockout and maybe other users had the same problem.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the "update" isn't working. Actually, I would recommend not using "updateAll" unless the content of the `thead` changes - use "update" instead. I don't know knockout.js well enough to help any more than this... :(

Comment: Thanks by your answer but It´s worng, look like when you use computed value, the computed value return an array but without sort method and indexOf and thie tableSorter use these 2 methods for managing this table............. is strange because only happen when you are working with index and the number of elements by page by default is 5.

Comment: Finally I resolved this problem here:
https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/915

Answer (score 1):

That's really strange. I have no idea how it works with observable array but there is one strange thing: setTimeout - what is the purpose of this? It's called asynchronously that means that ko.dependencyDetection is not able to track dependency on `valueAccessor()` (it works ONLY synchronously). So, according to this your binding invokes init method and that's it. It never calls `update` (only during initialization).

I propose this fix:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortTable = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var iden=$(element).attr("id");
    if($(element).hasClass('tablesorter')){
        $(element).trigger('updateAll');
    }else{
        $(element).tablesorter({
            widgetOptions:{filter_external : '#'+iden+"_search"}
            //headers: {0: {sorter: false}}
        })//.tablesorterPager({container: $('#'+iden+"_pager")});
    }
},

update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
  ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // adds dependency, so when associated observable value is changed "update" method will be triggered
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(element).trigger("update");
  }, 0);
}
```

};

**P.S.**: working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IW3Gp5NXB1lyLIRWseKM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks by your answer Serjio but I continue with teh same problem, with your solution I can add new elements yes, even I can delete elements. The problme is when you want use the control of tableSorter with the pagination for showing 5 elements or 10 elements. In this case everything is wrong and We need this pagination.

Comment: Finally I resolved this problem here:
https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/915